# Which loads faster: Loading a large image two times and scaling one OR loading the large image once and thumbnail

Tags: image, optimization, scale

I have a rotator that has a thumbnail and featured image.

- Featured.png: 1054 * 510 : 157.35kb
- Thumbnail.png: 190 * 75 : 3.67kb

Would it be faster on a mobile device to load the same image twice then scale one image to the thumbnail size or use two different images? I figured because the image is already cached it might be faster. I also think because I'm serving a scaled image that it may require more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Imho it is always smarter/better to load a `thumbnail` instead of the full size `image` when it is not needed.

-Imagine a `post` which holds 10 images in the content.

- `Thumbnails` are small and fast.
- Full size `images` will take often more than 10x the `thumbnail`
  size.
- (*down*)Scaling `images` is bad SEO and trying to achieve a wrong
  user experience when it is about big `images`. (*or imho a bit lazyness of the webdesigner*)
- WordPress is able to create different size images, including thumbnails. (*so please use them*)

When ppl browsing your site and want to read a `posting/page` they sometimes "just" want to read or to search some in the `content`. So please don't force them to download full size `images`. 
As soon they want to see the full `image` they will click on the `thumbnail` and then the full size `image` will be downloaded. The *user experience* is in that moment much better although they then have to "wait" for that full size `image`.

A page which holds 10 `thumbnails` with each a size of 3.7Kb and lets say 3.7Kb for content is "only" 41Kb. With full size `images` (*your example 157Kb*) that same page needs to load 1.6Mb. Meaning, with "only" `thumbnails` that page load is much much faster, and that for the same money...

Fast page loads and good content is all that invites a users to comeback again.
I think that it doesn't matter if they sit behind a desktop or looking on their smartphone, user experience is the key which always counts. Eventhough that often means, more work for the author :)

This is just seen from my perspective (*and experiences*) and maybe others have even better arguments for or against using `thumbnails`.

Comment: You wouldn't use a thumbnail for a full size image. So in order to display a full size image you'd **have** to load a full size image. Whereas you can use a full size image to display full screen and as a thumbnail, whether this is best practice or not....